# Emacs and git branches

Tags: git, emacs

This is my problem:

1. I am working with files from a local `git` repository in Emacs; I edit and save those files.
2. My Emacs session is still open. I commit my changes, then create a new branch and `checkout` that branch.
3. Returning to Emacs, I edit some more.
4. When I save those files Emacs warns me that the files have changed on disk and confirms if it should overwrite them.

It's not a huge problem, but it's kind of annoying. I wonder if there's any way to tell Emacs to refresh all buffers or if there's something else I could do?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RevertBuffer#toc2

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480572/how-to-have-emacs-auto-refresh-all-buffers-when-files-have-changed-on-disk

Comment: Obligatory "you should be using Magit" comment.